# get unmatched portion from string java 8

Tags: java, regex, java-8

i have my string as "I am new to Java (*) "

and my actual string is I am new to Java 8, i will be getting bunch of keys from my map, where in i need to extract the unmatched portion that is 8 here

my final map should consist a  the first string is the key and the value is the unmatched portion how would i do that in java 8

```
Pattern p =Pattern.compile("I am new to Java (*)");

map= map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getKey().contains("Java")&&p.getKey().matches("I am new to Java (*)"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

I am using the below one and it breaks, could some one advise?

i want something like

```
Map<String, String> result=map.entrySet().stream().filter(k-> k.getKey().matches(test) && k.getKey().contains(test))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k.getKey(), ::p.matcher().group(1)));
```

i was able to acheive it using two maps

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((k,v)->{
            if(k.contains(test)) {
                while(p.matcher(k).find()) {
                    result.put(k, p.matcher(k).group(1));
                }
            }
        });
```

but i want it in one map

Comment: Your regex is incorrect, looks like you want to use `I am new to Java (.*)` (`*` is a quantifier, it modifies the previous token by specifying how much times it should occur ; `(` isn't a quantifiable token ; `.`, which will match any character, is)

Comment: i use (.*) still it doesn't work

Comment: how doesn't it work? Is there an error message, or an unexpected result?

Comment: added it @Aaron

Comment: Your new map is created using `p.getValue()` as value, so you shouldn't expect the value to magically become the java version number captured by your regex. It looks like your filter is alright (although the first condition is redundant : if your regex match, the key obviously contains "Java") but your collector would need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to extract the first group from the matched text.

Comment: In other words so far you're only using your regex to check that the key conforms to a specific pattern. You want to additionally use it to extract a part of said text, which will require the use of Pattern & Matcher instead of a simple `String.matches(pattern)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly (and simplified your example a bit):

```
String test = "I am new to Java 8 ";
String t = "I am new to Java (.*) ";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(test, "value1");
map.put("some", "value2");

Map<String, String> result = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals(e.getKey().replaceAll(t, "$1")))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> e.getKey().replaceAll(t, "$1"),
                    Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Edited the question above

Comment: Edited the question @aaron

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("I am new to Java (.*)");
Predicate<String> regexFilter = p.asPredicate();

Function<String,String> versionExtractor = str -> {
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  if (m.find()) {
    return m.group(1);
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("It didn't match !"); // should never happen since we match beforehand
  }
};

Map<String,String> result = inputMap.keySet()
  .stream()
  .filter(regexFilter)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), versionExtractor));
```

If I'm not mistaken, the problem you encountered was that you couldn't map your key to your value in a single statement since you need to first `.matches` before you can `.group`.

We're so used to single-line lambdas (enabled by the power of functional programming) that we sometime forget that they are plain old `Function`s and that they have no such limitation. Here I defined my lambda using a `{statements}` block, and I affected that lambda to a variable which I was able to reference later in my stream handling. I could have defined that lambda directly inside the stream operations, or I could also have implemented a `Function` without using the lambda notation.

[Try it here](https://ideone.com/sZjWh6).